# Is there a way to bring back search the web for spotlight?

Tags: mac, finder, search, shortcut

Spotlight use to be my one stop shop for typing anything that I needed information about. When it would fail, the result saying "search in web" would come up and that was a really nice fallback when that issue occurred because it generally sent me where I needed to go through Google.

Now, Apple has decided that's not going to be a listed item any more thus forcing me to select all, cut everything I had typed, type safari and launch that, possibly open a new tab and paste the search in there. While I would be proud of that little combo of keyboard shortcuts, the old method was five steps faster so I feel a little foolish needing to do this now.

My question: is there a way to re-enable search the web or a tool somewhere in homebrew or github that will give me that back?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Flashlight](http://flashlight.nateparrott.com) Spotight plugin and install **Google Search** plugin. Then You'll be able to search Google inside Spotlight (just add `g` as a prefix). When You'll want to see the results in web browser, press <kbd>⏎ return</kbd>. Here's an example: [image]

Comment: Oh my dear sweet lord...

Answer (score 0):

When you are searching with Finder, run your search and then click on the Gear menu in the Finder window toolbar. Inside of there, you'll have an option to `Search with Google` - run it from there and it'll execute your search.

[image]

Comment: I think I might mean spotlight.. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Under **System Preferences**, select **Spotlight** and verify that web search is selected in the **Search Results** tab.

```
 > System Preferences... > Spotlight
```

In Yosemite, this is set to Bing. You can drag the categories to your order preference.

[image: System Preferences Spotlight settings]